# JavaScript: Post can't send parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, http, post

In my webpage, I try to send parameters by JavaScript.

When I get the request, I find the parameters is null? 
I am quite sure , the request can be sent successfully because I can receive the request.

I don't know why it is wrong, this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="kiben" content="no-cache">
<title>Login Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetCookie (name) 
{ 
    var arg = name + "="; 
    var alen = arg.length; 
    var clen = window.document.cookie.length; 
    var i = 0; 
    while (i < clen) 
    { 
        var j = i + alen; 
        if (window.document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg) return getCookieVal (j); 
        i = window.document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1; 
        if (i == 0)
            break; 
    } 
    return null;
}
function getCookieVal (offset)
{ 
    var endstr = window.document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset); 
    if (endstr == -1)
        endstr = window.document.cookie.length; 
    return unescape(window.document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
}
function SetCookie (name, value)
{ 
    var exp = new Date(); 
    exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (30*24*60*60*1000));
    window.document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) + "; expires=" + exp.toGMTString()+";path=/";
}
function DeleteCookie (name)
{ 
    var exp = new Date(); 
    exp.setTime (exp.getTime() - 100); 
    var cval = GetCookie (name); 
    window.document.cookie = name + "=" + cval + "; expires=" + exp.toGMTString()+";path=/";
}

function DelCookie()
{
    DeleteCookie(document.getElementById("username").value);
}
function remember()
{
    if(document.getElementById("remember").checked){
        SetCookie(document.getElementById("username").value,document.getElementById("password").value);
        alert("Saved!");
    }   
    createForm();
}
function showpassword()
{
     var p=GetCookie(document.getElementById("username").value);
     if(p!=null)
    document.getElementById("password").value= p;
}
function createForm(){
     var form = document.createElement("form");
     form.method="post";
     form.action="login";
     var usernmae = document.getElementById("username");
     var pwd = document.getElementById("password");
     var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
     hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "text");
     hiddenField.setAttribute("username",username.value);
     hiddenField.setAttribute("password",pwd.value);
     form.appendChild(hiddenField);  
     document.body.appendChild(form);
     form.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

        UserName:<input type="text" id="username" onblur="showpassword()"><br />
        Password:<input type="password" id="password">
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
        </input>Remeber Username<br />
        <input value="Submit" type="button" onClick="remember()"> 
        <input value="Delete" type="button" onClick="DelCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
     hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "text");
     hiddenField.setAttribute("username",username.value);
     hiddenField.setAttribute("password",pwd.value);
     form.appendChild(hiddenField);  
     document.body.appendChild(form);
     form.submit();
```

sending parameters like this is not possible
sending data by form submission needs `name attribute` on each of the html controls submitted

```
 var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
         hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "text");
         hiddenField.setAttribute("name","username");
         hiddenField.setAttribute("value",username.valuee);
         form.appendChild(hiddenField);

var hiddenField2 = document.createElement("input");
         hiddenField2.setAttribute("type", "text");
         hiddenField2.setAttribute("name","password");
         hiddenField2.setAttribute("value",pwd.value);
         form.appendChild(hiddenField2);

         document.body.appendChild(form);
         form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the most important thing in a `form` element.. the `form` it self.

How about wrapping the inputs in a big `<form...>` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `<form>` tag in your HTML to do this, instead of creating a form programatically.

```
<body>
    <form action="login" method="POST">
        UserName:<input type="text" id="username" onblur="showpassword()"><br />
        Password:<input type="password" id="password">
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
        </input>Remeber Username<br />
        <input value="Submit" type="button" onClick="remember()"> 
        <input value="Delete" type="button" onClick="DelCookie()">
    </form>
</body>
```

If you want to do this way (in JavaScript), you should create 2 `input` with createElement instead of just one.